# How can i show that If ${a_n} \rightarrow a $ then $\{a_{n-1}\}_{n=2}$ converges to $a$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can i show that If ${a_n} \rightarrow a $ then $\{a_{n-1}\}_{n=2}$ converges to $a$

Then by def $\forall \epsilon > 0 $ $\exists  N_0$ such that $\forall n\geq N_0$

$|a_n -a|<\epsilon$

And then $\forall \epsilon>0 $ and then  $\forall n\geq 2, n-1\geq N_0$
and this implies $|a_{n-1}-a|< \epsilon$

is right?

Comment: Sorry, but what does $\{a_{n-1}\}_{n=2}$ mean?

Comment: Set $b_n = a_{n-1}$.  By assumption, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n \geq N, |a_n - a| < \epsilon.$  Since this holds for $N$, it must also hold for $(N+1)$, because any $n \geq (N+1)$ must also be $\geq N$.  Then, you have that for all $n \geq N, |b_n - a| < \epsilon.$

Comment: @MJD the sequence $a_{n-1}$ starting from n=2

Comment: My previous comment shows how I would prove it.  In your analysis (i.e. your alternate method), it is not clear to me how you conclude that $\forall n \geq 2, (n-1) \geq N_0$.

Comment: @user2661923 just a question how do you get $n\geq N+1$

Comment: You have that for all $n \geq N, P(n)$, where $P(n)$ is some assertion.  This implies that $P(n)$ holds for set $S =  \{N, N+1, N+2, \cdots \}$.  Since it holds for set $S$, it must also hold for set $T \subseteq S$, where $T = \{N+1, N+2, \cdots\}.$  Therefore, $\forall n \geq (N+1), P(n)$.

Comment: choose $N'=N+1$.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, the sequence $\{a_{n-1}\}_{n\geq 2}$ should converge to a.

Essentially it doesn't matter if you start the sequence $\{a_{n-1}\}$ at $n = 2$, or $n=3$ or $n= 1467$. The important thing is, that in the limit $n \to \infty$ the sequence $\{a_{n-1}\}$ behaves exactly like the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$. So, the limit is still $a$.